# Gerrit Code Review behind Nginx Reverse Proxy in Docker with SSL

Tags: proxy, docker, nginx

Good Evening All,

I am struggling with getting Gerrit to work on Docker with Nginx Reverse Proxy, I am using the following Nginx & LetsEncrypt configuration: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

The Gerrit docker image I am using is: https://hub.docker.com/r/gerritcodereview/gerrit

When I run the Gerrit docker image, it successfully starts but when checking the Nginx configuration, the upstream server shows the IP address of the docker container but without the port number i.e. DOCKER CONTAINER IP:PORT NUMBER but instead as "down".

The goal is to be able to access Gerrit via https://gerrit.domainname.com, I have tried the official documentation from Gerrit but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help or advice will be much appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Mo

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do similar config. 
Nginx snippet:

```
upstream gerrit {
 server my_gerrit_ip:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
 listen 8080;   
 server_name my-gerrit-site.com;   
 return 301
 https://$host$request_uri; 
}

server {   
  listen 443 ssl;   
  server_name my-gerrit-site.com;
  ssl_certificate /share/certs/localhost.pem;   
  ssl_certificate_key /share/certs/localhost.key;

  location / {

        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_redirect      http:// https://;
        proxy_pass  http://gerrit;   } }
```

Gerrit snippet (gerrit.conf)

```
  [gerrit]
    canonicalWebUrl = https://my-gerrit-sice.com
  [httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-https://*:8080/
```

Remember to run gerrit with "CANONICAL_WEB_URL=https://my-gerrit-site.com" set in environment.